# PC to raspberry Pi via TCP/IP socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, server, client

I am trying to do wireless communications between a PC (macbook) and a Raspberry Pi 2 using python's socket module (python 2.7). The server is the PC and the client is the Pi.
When I run the code (server first then client) both scripts get stuck on the socket.accept() and socket.connect() methods respectfully.

What is funny is that when I do the reverse (Pi being the server and PC being the client) the code works fine, with data been sent correctly.

The scripts below are meant to loop forever whilst incrementing a counter sent over (I increment the port's after each succesful transfer to avoid '[Errno 48] Address already in use' (probably terrible practice I know))

My client script:

```
import socket
import sys

def read(port):
        s = socket.socket()
        host = '10.19.92.44' #(IP address of PC (server))
        s.connect((host,port))
        try:
                msg = s.recv(1024)
                s.close()
    except socket.error, msg:
            sys.stderr.write('error %s'%msg[1])
            s.close()
            print 'close'
            sys.exit(2)
    return msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 1025
    while True:
            print 'hey, checking TCP socket'
            data = read(port)
            print 'i just read %s' % data
            print 'port num is: %d' % port
            port = port + 1
```

My server script:

```
import socket
import time

def send(data, port):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('', port))
    s.listen(5)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Got connection from',addr
    c.send(data)
    c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 1025
    num = 1
while True:
            print 'hey, sending data'
            words = 'helloWorld'
            data = words + str(num)
            print 'send data: %s' % data
            send(data,port)
            port = port + 1
            num = num + 1
```

As I mentioned when I swap roles (and replace the server IP address in the client script to the Pis 172.17.33.125) the code works fine...

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an immediate answer, but I have a couple of ideas.

Your PC and Pi seem to be in different networks. The PC's address is `10.19.92.44`, while Pi's is `172.17.33.125`. There's a probability that `10.19.92.44` isn't the address you need. In order to find out what is the correct PC IP address to use in the application:

1. Issue `networksetup -listallhardwareports` to figure out the name of your wifi interface (should be like `en0`, `en1`).
2. Issue `ifconfig`, find the wifi interface. The IP address attached to this interface is the one you need.

Another option is to install wireshark on the PC, set up a working system (server-Pi, client-PC) and use wireshark to capture the traffic between the PC and Pi. Wireshark makes it easy to figure out IP addresses of both parties. I would advise to have this program installed whenever you want to debug a complicated networking issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You were right, they were on different networks. When I used ethernet with my PC and ethernet with the Pi it worked. Unfortunately I need wireless coms since it is for a robot, so I may have to opt for something a little more primitive - zigbee :(